# Create an Excel (2013) spreadsheet w Barcodes to track meals

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm not an Excel power user by any description, please pardon my lack of knowledge. I need to create a spreadsheet to track who eats meals, we serve two meals each day, breakfast and lunch.

I want to create a bar-code for each person. When that person scans their bar-code at the end of the line that meal is recorded for that day. I think it should be easy!

I can create the bar-codes with the ID Numbers. I can make it put the #1 in a cell for that meal on that day. I can not get it to go to the right row when the bar-code is scanned it just jumps down the next cell directly below the last cell.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: While that may not be the way you planned to order your spreadsheet, but for simplicity sake rather than change settings on the scanner or within excel, I would simply plan the spreadsheet so that the barcodes as scanned are being added to a column, then nothing needs to change.  Advancing one row is pretty standard, yes it can be changed but it might just be better to collect in a column

Comment: Is the barcode something you would tattoo on their forehead?  Sorry, it's just the image that comes to mind visualizing your question.

Comment: Tattooing their foreheads could be useful is many circumstances! However, I think getting parental consent could be problematic.

The USDA requires us to keep an "Accurate" count of each student that goes through the lunch line each day for each meal served.

Comment: Also, Getting students go go through the lunch line in the same order every day . . . I'd rather try to heard cats.

Answer (score 1):

The bar code scanner you are using is likely adding a carriage return after the scan. Depending on the scanner, somewhere in the setup you should be able to change this to a TAB.

If that option is not available, you can change the setup in Excel to tell it where to move when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed. This will change the behavior to move in the direction you like. Go to `File > Options > Advanced . Editing options`.

[image]

Comment: The barcode scanner is a old Follett 3800, basically it scans barcodes and using barcodes to set it's two options on all the time or trigger actuated and beep volume,

Comment: Did you try changing the option in Excel to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: I did, it doesn't make a difference in that it just moves to the next cell in that direction. If I uncheck the box, it continues to put the new information in the same cell and doesn't move at all. I guess it could be the scanner?

its an old Follett 3800 scanner.